# Wordpress: All Pages on one Page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to put together a theme that displays all "pages" on a single page. I'm assuming that the best place for this would be "index.php" ... and I want to make sure that my code is the proper way of doing this:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Also, is there a way to optionally NOT display sub-pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to exclude all sub pages is this:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ($post->post_parent != '') {
 the_title(); 
the_content(); 
} endwhile; endif; ?>
```